# Is MCTS (.net framework) recognised for Australia work visa?

Tags: working-visas, australia, skilled-migration

I'm willing to apply for Australian Visa, maybe 189 (Skilled Independant) or 190 (Skilled Sponsored) classes as a Software Developer.

My university degree is an Advanced Diploma (2 years university degree). I believe my AD gives me 10 points. I read in [this fellow's answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/9833/14230) that having an MCP can bring you 5 points. If that's true, am I right to say I can gain 15 points, 10 for my Advanced Diploma plus 5 for my Microsoft MCST certificate?

If this be true, it saves me a lot of time, and reduces pressure on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the question you linked, and while the answerer's post was correct at the time, it no longer holds. If you look at the [official information](http://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/supporting/Pages/skilled/qualifications-documents.aspx), you can now read that it is explicitly stated that:

> You will receive points for your highest qualification only.

I can recall exactly that a while earlier, it was not stated so explicitly, and (I assume) the person who wrote that answer could claim points because in that time, it was ambiguous and therefore legally attackable - perhaps that's why that statement had been reworded in the first place.

More precisely, back then, it was written that *"a maximum of 20 points may be claimed for the qualifications category"* or something like that. Based on that phrasing, it was reasonable to deduce that you may claim points for several different items under the qualifications category, but if the sum of items in that category exceeded 20, then you would be awarded 20 points and no more.